# How to use 'if' condition on histogram?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I want to put the long position when the previous 2 histogram candles are in ascending order

```
fast_length = input(title="Fast Length", defval=25)
slow_length = input(title="Slow Length", defval=100)
signal_length = input.int(title="Signal Smoothing",  minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 9)
src = input(title="Source", defval=close)
sma_source = input.string(title="Oscillator MA Type",  defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
sma_signal = input.string(title="Signal Line MA Type", defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
// Plot colors
col_grow_above = input(#26A69A, "Above   Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_fall_above = input(#B2DFDB, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_grow_below = input(#FFCDD2, "Below Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
col_fall_below = input(#FF5252, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
// Calculating
fast_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, fast_length) : ta.ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, slow_length) : ta.ema(src, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = sma_signal == "SMA" ? ta.sma(macd, signal_length) : ta.ema(macd, signal_length)
hist = macd - signal
```

i  want to put long position  if the histogram is negative

```
if hist < 0  and  hist [2] > hist [1]
    strategy.entry("long2",strategy.long,100)
```

and if the hist is positive

```
if hist >0 and hist[1]>hist[2]
    strategy.entry("long2",strategy.long,100)
```

but my method is not working, I don't why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that your code work as intended. You should be carefull to write

```
hist[2]
```

and not

```
hist [2]
```

I added this at the end of your code :

```
if hist < 0  and  hist[2] > hist[1]
    label.new(bar_index,hist,"N")
if hist > 0 and hist[1] > hist[2]
    label.new(bar_index,hist,"P")
```

and I get this result :

[image]